# Delimiter matching simple program won't work

Tags: c++, stream, delimiter

I have looked over this for hours it seems like. This program will compile, it just can't detect errors correctly. And for some reason it will work when I type in hey [) or hey {], etc. But it won't work for hey[) or hey{]. Obviously in all cases it should detect an error but for some reason the space after 'hey' makes a difference.

```
#include<iostream>
#include <stack>
using namespace std;

bool delimiterMatching(char *file){
  stack<char> x;
  int count = 0;
  char ch, onTop, check;
  while(ch != '\0'){
    ch = file[count];
    if (ch == '(' || ch == '[' || ch == '{')
      x.push(ch);
    else if (ch == ')' || ch ==  ']' || ch == '}') {
      onTop == x.top();
       x.pop();
      if((ch==')' && onTop!='(') || (ch==']' && onTop!='[') || (ch=='}' && 
                                onTop!= '{'))
    return false;
    }
  count++;
  }

  if (x.empty())
    return true;
  else 
    return false;

}


int main()
{
  char *test = new char();
  cout << "enter sentence: ";
  cin >> test;

  if (delimiterMatching(test))
    cout << "success" << endl;
  else 
    cout << "error" << endl;

  return 1;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

With `cin >> test` you don't get a whole sentence, but only a string until cin encounters whitespace. So if you type `(hey )`, thest would be `(hey` and the closing brace would only be read by the next `>>`, whereas `(hey)` would work as expected.

You have a second issue with your `test` allocation, which might be too short for reasonable input.

Change main() as follows:

```
char *test = new char[256];   // enough space.  COnsider also string  
cout << "enter sentence: ";
cin.getline(test, 256);       // full line input. 
...
```

You have also two nasty bugs in `delimiterMatching()`.

- First you use an uninitialized `ch` in your `while` condition. Either initialise ch to a non nul char, or use `while (file[count])`.
- And did you notice `onTop == x.top();`  ?  Shouldn't it be `onTop = x.top();`?

Comment: Thank you! looks like fixing onTop = xtop() fixed a lot. And thanks for your explanation of the spaces! Also, how would you initialize test to be a string variable? Because I can't pass string into a char* function. Sorry for such stupid questions.

Comment: Lastly, I don't understand why while(file[count]) doesn't go into an infinite loop since count is always incrementing.

Comment: because `while(file[count])` means the same than `while(file[count]!='\0')`.  FOr the string topic, as your delilimerMatching reads only, you can define its parameter to be `const char*`, so if test is a string, you can pass `test.c_str()` as argument